# Magento 1.7.0.2 mail notification not working

Tags: magento-1.7, email, transactional-mail, order-email

I had developed a ecommerce portal using magento 1.7.0.2, portal was working great and there is no problem with backend. But, i am facing a big trouble with email notification.

When user register, order confirmation, order updates etc. For any process, email notification not functioning.

Looking for the best support to fix this one.

thanks

Comment: check `mail server` is installed or not in server , also check cron jobs are working or not.... also make sure you entered valid email address in backend under `system>configuration>sales>email>order emails` section....

Comment: @BabyinMagento Yes, i had test with php mail function with my server (root folder for magento) it's wotking fine.

Comment: what about other emails like `contact-us , forget password` emails.... also check in spam folder once....

Comment: @BabyinMagento system>configuration>sales>email>order emails section having valid mail address only. Contact form throwing error like this "Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is problem with your SMTP configuration,

You may use this SMTP extension for custom SMTP and you can use your own emial service providor like Gmail and check if its working or not.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

Comment: SMTP pro working great, yes there is a problem with smtp connection now no issue. thanks

Comment: You are always welcome :)